# passing props to a props given component react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following function which takes an array of React components, and returns the same array but passes the `key` prop to these components automatically:

```js
const keyIt = (components) => {
  const keyedComponents = components.map((Component, i)=> <Component key={i}/>)
  return keyedComponents
}
```

## Usage:

```js
const Sidenav = (props)=> {
  return (keyIt([
    <ListItem>Home</ListItem>,
    <ListItem>About</ListItem>,
    <ListItem>Contact</ListItem>,
    <ListItem>Downloads</ListItem>,
    <ListItem>Plans</ListItem>,
  ]))
}
```

It's a simple utility that I wanted to create to automatically pass the key prop to ignore the errors (only when I know that the order of the list is never going to change).

But it doesn't work, and it shows the following error:

```
Warning: React.jsx: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: <ForwardRef(ListItem) />. Did you accidentally export a JSX literal instead of a component?
```

[image]

What's the problem? How can I solve this?

Comment: Just a side note: Using an index as a key is an anti-pattern in the general case, see [this article](https://robinpokorny.com/blog/index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern/) and [the React documentation that links to it](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys). It's okay if the array is **static**, but not if it isn't.

Comment: Maybe the solution is by using react `cloneElement` function? https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#cloneelement, but perhaps this would prevent the state of these elements to be re-rendered when their state changes via props, for example, when any of the sidenav elements is clicked, I want to highlight the selected element via a prop `selected: true`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error says, `<ListItem>Home</ListItem>` creates an *element*, not a component, but you're trying to use it as a component. (More about elements [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/rendering-elements.html) and about components [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html).)

Instead, to do this, you'd have to pass the component and the props you wanted it to have, and then create the element in the `map`, like this:

```
const keyIt = (components) => {
    const keyedComponents = components.map(({Component, props}, i) => <Component key={i} {...props} />);
    return keyedComponents;
};

const Sidenav = (props) => {
    return keyIt([
        {Component: ListItem, props: {children: "Home"}},
        {Component: ListItem, props: {children: "About"}},
        {Component: ListItem, props: {children: "Contact"}},
        {Component: ListItem, props: {children: "Downloads"}},
        {Component: ListItem, props: {children: "Plans"}},
    ]);
};
```

But please [note my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74087006/passing-props-to-a-props-given-component-react#comment130807926_74087006) above, `key={i}` is usually an anti-pattern.

You can make it less verbose by using `[component, props, children]` tuples:

```
const keyIt = (components) => {
    const keyedComponents = components.map(([Component, props, children], i) => (
        <Component key={i} {...props}>
            {children}
        </Component>
    ));
    return keyedComponents;
};

const Sidenav = (props) => {
    const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);
    useEffect(() => {
        const handle = setInterval(() => {
            setCounter((c) => c + 1);
        }, 1000);
        return () => {
            clearInterval(handle);
        };
    }, []);
    return keyIt([
        [ListItem, null, "Home"],
        [ListItem, null, "About"],
        [ListItem, null, "Contact"],
        [ListItem, null, "Downloads"],
        [ListItem, null, "Plans"],
    ]);
};
```

Live Example *(I've added state to `Sidenav` in the example just to show that the elements are correctly re-rendered when their props changed, since you thought in a comment that wouldn't happen)*:

```js
const { useState, useEffect } = React;

const ListItem = ({children}) => <div>{children}</div>;

const keyIt = (components) => {
    const keyedComponents = components.map(({ Component, props }, i) => (
        <Component key={i} {...props} />
    ));
    return keyedComponents;
};

const Sidenav = (props) => {
    const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);
    useEffect(() => {
        const handle = setInterval(() => {
            setCounter((c) => c + 1);
        }, 1000);
        return () => {
            clearInterval(handle);
        };
    }, []);
    return keyIt([
        { Component: ListItem, props: { children: `Home (${counter})` } },
        { Component: ListItem, props: { children: "About" } },
        { Component: ListItem, props: { children: "Contact" } },
        { Component: ListItem, props: { children: "Downloads" } },
        { Component: ListItem, props: { children: "Plans" } },
    ]);
};
const Example = () => {
    return <Sidenav />;
};

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(<Example />);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.1.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.1.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

Or the tuple version:

```js
const { useState, useEffect } = React;

const ListItem = ({children}) => <div>{children}</div>;

const keyIt = (components) => {
    const keyedComponents = components.map(([Component, props, children], i) => (
        <Component key={i} {...props}>
            {children}
        </Component>
    ));
    return keyedComponents;
};

const Sidenav = (props) => {
    const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);
    useEffect(() => {
        const handle = setInterval(() => {
            setCounter((c) => c + 1);
        }, 1000);
        return () => {
            clearInterval(handle);
        };
    }, []);
    return keyIt([
        [ListItem, null, `Home (${counter})`],
        [ListItem, null, "About"],
        [ListItem, null, "Contact"],
        [ListItem, null, "Downloads"],
        [ListItem, null, "Plans"],
    ]);
};

const Example = () => {
    return <Sidenav />;
};

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(<Example />);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.1.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.1.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

Comment: But this would prevent the elements to be re-rendered when any of their props gets changed

Comment: @Normal - What makes you think that?

Comment: Actually, I don't know. But I used to have problems with that in the past, I'm not sure if this is solved now in React 18

Comment: Would using react `cloneElement` function achieve the exact same behavior of this solution?

Comment: @Normal - I've added a live example. It's in v18, but the above would work just fine in React v17 as well as v18.

Comment: @Normal - Truthfully, I haven't used `cloneElement`. It seems inefficient to have a component render an element and then just clone it, as opposed to using the component instead. But reading the docs, sure, seems like that would work. (If you're worried about the verbosity of the object literals, you could use a function to make that more concise: `keyIt([x(ListItem, null, "Home"),/*...*/])`. Or actually, even just tuples: `keyIt([ [ListItem, null, "Home"],/*...*/ ])`.)